How to synchronize a producer consumer problem with two mutexes?
I'm currently working on a homework assignment for my university.  We are supposed to make a circular buffer threadsafe, given a struct rbuf with two mutexes and two signals. The two mutexes can possibly be traced back to the fact that two writer and two reader threads are always active. The read and write functions work very well so far, as all tests without testing the thread safety beforehand were successful. They are basically only responsible for writing to the buffer and reading from the buffer. Also we should use pthread_cond_timedwait. My current implementation always has data races (I know this thanks to the ThreadSanitizer) and unfortunately I have absolutely no idea how to synchronize this better.
This is my code so far, what am doing from this makes perfectly sense to me:
/*
typedef struct {
    uint8_t* read;
    uint8_t* write;
    uint8_t* begin;
    uint8_t* end;
    pthread_mutex_t mutex_read;
    pthread_mutex_t mutex_write;
    pthread_cond_t signal_read;
    pthread_cond_t signal_write;
} rbuf;
*/

int producer(rbuf *buffer, void *message, size_t message_len) {
    int val;
    struct timespec to;
    while (1) {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&buffer->mutex_write);
        clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &to);
        to.tv_sec += 1;
        val = write(buffer, message, message_len);
        if (val == 1 //SUCCESS) {
            pthread_cond_signal(&buffer->signal_read);
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&buffer->mutex_write);
            return retval;
        }
        if (pthread_cond_timedwait(&buffer->signal_write, &buffer->mutex_write, &to) == ETIMEDOUT) {
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&buffer->mutex_write);
            return val;
        }
    }
}

int consumer(rbuf *buffer, void *buffer_read, size_t *buffer_len) {
    int val;
    struct timespec to;
    while (1) {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&buffer->mutex_read);
        clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &to);
        to.tv_sec += 1;
        val = read(buffer, buffer_read, buffer_len);
        if (val == 1 //SUCCESS) {
            pthread_cond_signal(&buffer->signal_write);
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&buffer->mutex_read);
            return retval;
        }
        if (pthread_cond_timedwait(&buffer->signal_read, &buffer->mutex_read, &to) == ETIMEDOUT)  {
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&buffer->mutex_read);
            return val;
        }
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&buffer->mutex_read);
    }
}

I have tried several implemtations but this one is by far the best. A producer writes and sends the signal when writing was successful. The consumer does the same. The two functions are in a while loop because that made sense to me, but I don't know if that's right.

I see warnings that ThreadSanitizer is beta stage. Unless what is saying makes sense to you, it may very well be wrong. It is hard to tell what your code does without seeing the read and write functions. But it is likely that those two should be mutually excluded and you need to acquire the same lock(s) to call either of them. (if you do take both locks, this may turn into an exercise about deadlocks)

The two mutexes can possibly be traced back to the fact that two writer and two reader threads are always active. I certainly could be missing something, but what's preventing the read and write threads from stomping on each other? It looks and sounds like these mutexes synchronize only the read threads or only the write threads. Presumably read and write threads are all sharing the same buffer, there needs to be something that prevents reading and writing of the same memory at the same time. The only-conditional unlock of mutex_write also looks fishy to me.

Hey guys! thank you for your answers. unfortunately i also don't understand why there are two mutexes, but unfortunately that's what the task specifies. but surely there must be a solution with two mutexes, right? maybe lock both always?

Actually you could dedicate one mutex to signalling conditions and the other one to protecting read/write from each other. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4062126/can-2-pthread-condition-variables-share-the-same-mutex

thank you very much! i have now looked at the question but don't quite understand how this could help me. can you perhaps go into this in more detail? thank you

The way your code is, you could use one lock for everything, e.g. mutex_write. You can try rewriting all uses of mutex_read to mutex_write to see if your data races go away.

I still have data races but now the program does not terminate.

is there anything specific I have to consider while using timedwait instead of wait?

Currently, you are getting a data race because the producer and consumer are locking different mutexes. I am assuming that the read() and write() functions both look at the read and write pointers.
When writing to the buffer, the write() function checks the distance between the write pointer and the read pointer to figure out if it has space to write, then it writes the data. However, while this is going on, the read function could read some data out and increment the value of the read pointer, and that is what ThreadSanitizer is complaining about.
Your current code can deadlock in the following way:
A producer thread tries to write to the buffer but sees that it is full. Before it has a chance to wait on the condition variable though, it gets pre-empted and sleeps for a bit. While it is sleeping, a reader thread comes in, reads all of the data in the buffer and signals the condition variable. Condition variables are not 'sticky.' In other words, if no one is waiting on it, the signal is lost.
The producer thread then wakes up and sleeps on the condition variable. Because the buffer is empty, no reader thread is going to wake up and signal that there is more space available. The producer thread will then wait for the condition to time out.
I am not sure what your professor is trying to get you to accomplish with the two mutexes. Using a single mutex with two condition variables would make a lot more sense to me. In this case, if the producer and consumer were to use the same mutex, I would expect that there would be no race condition.
Its possible the professor is trying to get you to do a reader/writer lock to reduce contention under some work loads. In that case the producer would first lock the write lock then the read lock. While the consumers would only lock the read lock, but I am grasping at straws with that explanation.

thank you very much for your answer! in the case where the producer locks both mutexes would the producer still need to wait for a signal?

i`ve also encountered now the problem that the test just doesn't terminates while using valgrind any ideas why?
